# How does disk utility show negative disk usage for a USB Drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, disk-space, disk-utility

I have a 16GB (I think) USB flash drive.

When mounting under OS X, the disk utility reports a capacity of `16.71GB`, and available space of `18.52GB`. And therefore shows that I have used `-1.81GB` of space!

[image: An image of the drive in Disk Utility.]

How can the usage be calculated as negative? Surely the operating system would have checks for that... but if so, they are not functioning here.

I understand that people can tamper with a USB's firmware to make it show different capacities (e.g. a 2GB USB reports it holds 8GB), but what is happening in this case? The USB is being honest about it's capacity of ~16GB, it seems to be disk utility that is screwing up. Is this possibly related to how available space is calculated? Is the USB's firmware corrupt?

Comment: I have seen the same case with a USB drive.  It's an old drive that I THINK should have 1 GB of space.  It similarly shows the space by providing a low capacity of 0.2 GB, a negative space of -0.8GB, and a total of ~ 1GB.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson That is interesting. There is also a [similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/68069/i-have-a-broken-usb-drive-that-shows-as-two-physical-disks-one-with-a-negative?rq=1) here on super user. But the answer simply states it is a hardware problem. I'm more interested in _how_ and _why_ this happens. Thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because @Puqeko showed more interest in my comment.  I thought I would provide more information.  This is not an ***answer***, I'm afraid, but it will provide a bit more information on the error I experienced, which I think is the same:

---

## "Initial" drive state:

I found a thumb drive in my house.  It was fairly old; I checked its contents, and found it empty.  However, I also found this on the Mac's "info" (Command-I in Finder) and "Disk Utility":

Mac's Info from Finder:

[image: Mac's Info from Finder]

Disk Utility:

[image: Disk Utility Details]

As you'll note in both cases (using either method), there is a capacity of only 129 MB, but an available of 704 MB.  Disk Utility will even claim that I am using "`-575 MB`".

The truth is that it was empty, I used Disc Utility to erase it all, actually.

---

I re-erased the drive using Disk Utility, this time with the "slow & secure" erase.  No difference, it all looked the same.  Aside from the screen shots above, I also looked at the drive using `df -h`.

[image: Linux df command from Terminal]

Via linux, the drive is still showing only `129 MB` capacity, but more importantly, it does not have any of the `-575 MB` used, and it does not show the `704 MB` remaining.  So things look normal in the command line.

---

## After adding a file:

I then tried to put some files that were larger than 129 MB onto the drive, no luck.  So, it seems, the drive really is only 129 MB.  I then put a smaller file on the drive (~ 103 MB), and both Finder & Disk Utility looked as expected:

Finder:

[image: Finder info, after adding a file]

Disk Utility:

[image: Disk Utility, after adding a file]

---

## Summary

I here replicated the problem the OP had, showed that - in my case - the negative space was false, and showed that I could get things to "look normal" simply after changing its state, in this case, by adding a file.

Not much help, but at least it gave a means to reproduce, and another example.

Comment: This does seem to replicate the issue. However, I tried coping `~1GB` worth of files across after reading the above. It now says `-813MB` used, `19.52GB` available??? The USB drive I have was also _supposed_ to be empty in the question. However, it is relatively new (2 months old). Interesting how Mac's "info" displays `--` yet disk utility displays `-575.4` (this is also true on my machine). I still cannot find anywhere on the net that can explain this behaviour. Thanks for adding your info. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome!  We'll see if anyone with further details can chime in with real answers...  ;-p